# How can I top align AND left align a box flush with the top of a paragraph?

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

Using a box technique ([Paragraph numbers at left margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250636/paragraph-numbers-at-left-margin)), I added margin text.

**I'd like the top of the left-aligned number to be flush with the top of the paragraph text** rather than having the baselines aligned.

I am hoping to learn a box trick here. (I can do this with `tikz`, but *I'd like to learn how to do it with TeX or LaTeX boxes*) I tried adding a third `\makebox[0pt][t]{1.}` but I could not get it to align as desired. Is minipage the only/best way? My skills got a little weak after the Christmas vacation :=)

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\newcommand{\marginnum}[1]{\makebox[0mm][r]{\makebox[12mm][l]{\Huge\bfseries #1.}}}
\begin{document}
\marginnum{1}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

## Desired Output using TikZ

Using a similar \makebox of zero-width technique, I create an inline node on the first line of the paragraph. I then anchor a second node to the top of that node containing my margin text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\newcommand{\marginnum}[1]{%
\makebox[0pt][r]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
\node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (parstart) {\phantom{L}};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north east,font=\bfseries\Huge] at ($ (parstart.north west)+(-12mm,0) $) {#1.};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\begin{document}
\marginnum{1}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raise it into position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newcommand{\marginnum}[1]{%
  \makebox[0mm][r]{%
    \makebox[12mm][l]{%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.6\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\Huge\bfseries #1.}}}}

\begin{document}

\marginnum{1}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

---

A more *exact* method for the vertical position would be to use identify the height of some capital letter in the current font, and raise the number into position relative to that:

```
\newcommand{\marginnum}[1]{%
  \makebox[0mm][r]{%
    \makebox[12mm][l]{%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\fontcharht\font`A}[0pt][0pt]{\Huge\bfseries #1.}}}}
```

Comment: How did you choose the `.6\baselineskip`? I was considering to use `calc`'s `\heightof` command.

Comment: @jakun: Yes, one can perform a specific calculation using `\settoheight` (no [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) needed) to obtain the exact height. A `(` is typically used to measure the height of a rule in the form of a `\strut`, so this depends on the height of the tallest element in the line. In this case though, I just eye-balled it.

Comment: And will is this scalable? What happens if I decide to change the paragraph font size. Is there any way to replace `.6` with something relative to the font size itself? Oh I guess jakun beat me to the punch.

Comment: @macmadness86: The `.6` *is* relative to the font size since it uses `\baselineskip`. Try it with `\Large\marginnum{1}\lipsum[1]`.

Comment: @Werner Ok great! I am interested in the `\settoheight` calculation to get the precise factor. But I'll give you the answer check anyway.

Comment: @macmadness86: I've added an updated `\marginnum` that measures the height of some capital letter and places the number relative to that.

Comment: No need for `\@tempdima`: ``\dimexpr-\height+\fontcharht\font`A``

Comment: @egreg: Now isn't that nice, thanks. Shaved off a whole bunch of bytes.

Answer (score 5):

Set the object in a “top” `\parbox` with the reference point established with a zero height object and raise it the height of a capital letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\marginnumwidth}
\setlength{\marginnumwidth}{12mm}

\newcommand{\marginnum}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \hspace*{-\marginnumwidth}%
  \raisebox{\fontcharht\font`A}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \parbox[t]{\marginnumwidth}{\vspace*{0pt}\Huge #1.}%
  }%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\marginnum{1}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `\ignorespaces` here? I seem to be having a space issue (in my actual document, not my minimal example)

Comment: @macmadness86 So I don't need to worry about having `\marginnum` on a line by itself

Comment: I think making `\marginnumwidth` dynamic is more robust. For future reference, you did it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312581/how-to-calculate-width-of-remaining-part-of-line

Answer (score 4):

As I had almost the same solution as Werner, I'll add another solution based on the `lettrine`  package. The number font size is slighly larger since base line of the number aligns with the second line of text by default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{lettrine} \usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\newcommand{\marginnum}[1]{\makebox[0mm][r]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height +1.55ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[12mm][l]{\Huge\bfseries #1.}}}}

\newcommand{\varmarginnum}[1]{\lettrine[lhang=1, nindent=0pt]{\bfseries\makebox[12mm][l]{1.}}{}}

\begin{document}

\marginnum{1}\lipsum[1]

\varmarginnum{1}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]